# Vue.js dependent select

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue.js

I'm in very beginning stage learning Vue.js and encountered problem I can't figure out right now. So I have 1 select field:

```
data: {
  list: {
    'Option 1': [ { size:'1',prize:'5' }, { size:'2',prize:'10' } ]
  }
}
```

Then I populating first select field like this:

```
<select v-model="firstOptions" v-on:change="onChange">
  <option v-for="(item, index) in list">{{ index }}</option>
</select>
```

At this point everything is fine, but how to populate another select field based on first select? I need to access size and price.

I'm think this should be done here:

```
methods: {
  onChange: function() {
   // get options for second select field
  }
}
```

Comment: you can predefine a dependantSelectArray. On the onChange method you can fill it with select datas. So you can v-for on that dependantSelectArray and its sub values. And also you can set the model as depentandOptions['key-for-your-select'].

Comment: Yes I do understand this logic, but I don't understand how to code it.
For excample console.log( this.list ) brings me whole list, but I can't get specific selected item from that list.

Comment: you named it firstOptions. It might be changing when you select another value. In onChange menu you can console.log(app.firstOptions)

Comment: Yes, just made typo. If I console.log it it will give me object with whole list.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm assuming here in your data structure, `list`, that the value of each property defines the options you will use in the second select. The key here is the model for the first select drives the options for the second.

```
<option v-for="option in list[firstOption]" value="option.size">{{option.prize}}</option>
```

I'm not sure how exactly you want your text and values laid out in the first or second selects, but here is an example.

```
new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data: {
    firstOption: null,
    secondOption: null,
    list: {
      'Option 1': [ { size:'1',prize:'5' }, { size:'2',prize:'10' } ],
      'Option 2': [{size:'3', prize:'8'}]
    }
  }
})
```

and in your template

```
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="firstOption">
    <option v-for="(item, index) in list">{{ index }}</option>
  </select>
  <select v-model="secondOption" v-if="firstOption">
    <option v-for="option in list[firstOption]" value="option.size">{{option.prize}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

[Example in codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aJOOOe?editors=1010).

Comment: Yes, more clear now thanks. I already implemented this in little diferent way, changed jSON structure and doing onclick event v-on:click="onclick(firstListItemObj)" then in method onclick I can access firstListItemObj and return this.secondListItemObj = firstListItemObj.options

Yeah ant I changed select to ul, so here I doing onClick not onChange.